# Authenticate User via a e-mailed link

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm fairly new to user authentication, but have built some standard user authentication processes in PHP. To get to the point I've been tasked to build a system that we can send out a mass e-mail blast to users that includes a link which the user can click on and be directly logged into the system.

I will probably be building this using codeigniter. If anyone could provide some direction on a procedure to follow or some tutorials on this it would be extremely helpful. Note: if they're not codeigniter specific that is completely fine.

Comment: Just use the user (id/name) and a nonce (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to generate a hash based on the username and some kind of salt, and then put a link in the email something like `http://some.url/loggedin.php?email=<email>&hash=<hash>` that way the email can be used to look up the record in the db easily and the hash can be compared.

Hope that helps

Comment: Ya that's what I got from reading around. Was just wondering if anyone had a good tutorial or a codeigniter walk through. Thanks!

Comment: So I just wanted to clarify this statement. All I need to do is create a salt and associate that with the user in the database and then put that in a URL with some kind of information that I can reference the user with?

Comment: @James Parker yes, you can do that, or you can use the same salt for all users. It's just to stop people from being able to use somebody else's email too easily

Answer (score 0):

I worked on it before!i had a members table with following fields :

```
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `birthday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `regDate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastLogin` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
```

when clients attempt to signup, you must give their `username`, `password`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `birthday`
then insert a record in the table!but set status to `'pending'` and send an email with hashed username to email that contain an url like this `http://www.mysite.com/signup.php?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(hashed username)`

you must prevent to login users who their status are 'penidng'

when a user come back but her/his url that send to email check your table that is verifyed or not if it's ok update status to for example 'normal' you can use status in future for something like blocking user and set status to block if you want to block a user